# Detail views fail to find post url after adding one to many fk relationship from "PostFile" to "Post"

Tags: django, url

After changing `admin.py` (previous code commented):

```
# admin.site.register(Post)
class PostFileAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = PostFile


@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PostFileAdmin]


@admin.register(PostFile)
class PostFileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

And adding `PostFile` to `models.py`:

```
class Post(models.Model):

 slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique_for_date="date_posted")
    content = RichTextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("news:news-detail",
                            args=[self.date_posted.year,
                                self.date_posted.month,
                                self.date_posted.day,
                                self.slug])

class PostFile(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_file = models.FileField(upload_to="files/news", null=True, blank=True)
```

Also, `views.py`:

```
  class PostListView(ListView):
      model = Post
      template_name = "news/news_home.html"
      context_object_name = "posts"
      ordering = ["-pk"]
      paginate_by = 2


def news_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post, 
                                    status="published",
                                    date_posted__year=year,
                                    date_posted__month=month,
                                    date_posted__day=day)
    
    return render(request, "news/news_detail.html", {"post": post,})
```

When I create new post in Django admin, and then try to go to its absolute_url to see detailed view, it raises `404`. I checked, using shell, absolute_url is good and all objects are created properly, but for some reason post's URL is broken. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Maybe the `status="published"` filter causing the `404`

Comment: You are right, I changed the `default` argument to "draft" from "published "sometime ago and it seems it now got updated with the latest migrations. Thank you!